# cordova android build fail when firebase-auth plugin add

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have not been able to build Android since I added the FireBase plugin to my project.

I am developing with ionic.
And we have added several plugins.

i tried  cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release plugin add 
but not working

i tried find 'google-play-serivce version' in my project and replace 15.+ but not working!

in my cordova plugin list:

```
cordova-admob-plus 0.0.0 "@admob-plus/cordova"
cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release 2.0.0 "cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release"
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 2.0.0 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.15 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 3.2.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication 1.0.1 "cordova-plugin-firebase-authentication"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-support-android-plugin 1.0.1 "cordova-support-android-plugin"
cordova-support-google-services 1.2.1 "cordova-support-google-services"
```

and when i build android the err message is:

```
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
    at build_5rihf9su8setcaecvlg313jed.run(/Users/dev_pjw/Documents/workspace/bmdevs/tgc-clinet-app/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:152)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/dev_pjw/Documents/workspace/bmdevs/tgc-clinet-app/platforms/android/cordova-support-google-services/tgc-build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
/Users/dev_pjw/Documents/workspace/bmdevs/tgc-clinet-app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

i tried  cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release plugin add 
but not working

i tried find 'google-play-serivce version' in my project and replace 15.+ but not working!

Is there a way to firebase-auth plugin add ??

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-support-google-services#build-error-failed-to-apply-plugin-class-comgooglegmsgoogleservicesgoogleservicesplugin

Comment: Maybe this will help to you https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-support-google-services/issues/15#issuecomment-459993224